# Update Windows 10 from ISO without losing data

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-update, iso-image

I was wondering if I can update my Windows 10 from a USB, using an ISO.

I have had problems updating for about a year, and tried everything.

My Windows 10 never updates, and is still stuck on 1703.

It has been so long since update, that I now have a desktop shortcut called `Windows 10 Update Assistant`, which I have run 3 times now.

The last run, I got error code `0x80070002` (Something to do with `Did not find hard disk space needed`).

Here is my error log (`C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log`):

```
2018-02-25 11:23:22, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Suspend(1066): Result = 0xC1800104
2018-02-25 11:23:22, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(723): Result = 0x800705BB
2018-02-25 11:23:22, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(347): Result = 0x800705BB
2018-02-25 11:23:22, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(237): Result = 0x800705BB
2018-02-25 11:23:22, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(375): Result = 0x800705BB
2018-02-25 11:34:30, Error                 SP     CDownloadDUUpdates::DoExecuteInternal: Did not find hard disk space needed, when update cab files will not be extracted. This is unexpected! hr = 0x8000ffff
2018-02-25 11:34:30, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: Failed to download updates. Error: 0x8000FFFF
2018-02-25 11:34:30, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute GDR search and download [0x8000ffff]
2018-02-25 11:35:13, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to set WU internal configuration property for targeted scans. hr = 0x80070057
2018-02-25 11:35:13, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::BuildSearchCriteria: Caller profile search criterion is not supported. hr = 0x80070032
2018-02-25 11:35:13, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to build the search criteria. hr = 0x80070032
2018-02-25 11:43:28, Error                 CONX   0xd0000034 Failed to add user mode driver [%SystemRoot%\system32\DRIVERS\UMDF\uicciso.dll]

2018-02-25 11:49:12, Error                 IBSLIB BCD: Failed to add system store from file. File: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Boot\BCD Status: c000000f[gle=0x00000003]
2018-02-25 11:49:12, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionDiskSpaceReq::CalculateRequiredDiskSpaceInstallReq(1771): Result = 0x80070002[gle=0x00000003]
2018-02-25 11:49:13, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionDiskSpaceReq::ExecuteInstallReq(1283): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:13, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionDiskSpaceReq::ExecuteRoutine(504): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:13, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IDiskSpaceAction> > > >::Execute(441): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:13, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteAction(3243): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:13, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteActions(3397): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:13, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Execute(1631): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:13, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2170): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:13, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2133): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:13, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(715): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:13, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(347): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:18, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(237): Result = 0x80070002
2018-02-25 11:49:18, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(375): Result = 0x80070002
```

[Full log here](https://pastebin.com/raw/8dQWg1m3)

Anyway, I was wondering if I could update my Windows 10 to the latest update, via ISO, without losing all of my data.

SYSTEM SPECS:
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJkci.png)
I also have a dual boot setup, with Kali Linux (I do lots of security stuff), with GRUB boot-loader.

DISK SPACE:
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rs4P.png)

Comment: You don't mention...do you have enough free space, or is that why the update fails?

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/876183/joshua-angel) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/876187/joshua-angel). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

From the error, are you sure your Windows partition doesn’t run out of space when upgrading? A larger upgrade could use quite a bit of space, especially temporarily.

You can try an in-place upgrade from an install medium, like an iso or a Windows USB stick. Plug the pen drive and launch “setup.exe”. You should get to install updates and then upgrade, choosing to keep your apps and data.

I had some trouble doing this with a fairly broken Windows installation a while back. It only eventually worked when I used the USB installer, and told it not to save my apps or data. I don’t know if this is common or not, but the install worked and functionality was restored. This also did not touch my dual boot setup of Ubuntu.

Of course you should absolutely make sure to have full backups of any important data in any OS on the machine before proceeding, just because.

Good luck!